# How to enable the HTTP method overriding in CXF3

Tags: spring, apache, cxf, apache-httpclient-4.x, cxf-client

How to enable the HTTP method overriding in CXF3?

According to cxf3 docuemntations, even though CXF supports overriding request methods, by default this is not allowed (since CXF 3.3.4) for a CXF service[1][2].

[1] https://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html

[2] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-8133